# How to get rid of specific tabnine recommendation in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Tabnine recommendations are quite useful but one of the most annoying recommendations is shown in the image below and it comes as soon as I type colon sign.

[image]

I don't know why it recommends this snippet but it's very annoying and I literally never needed it. The worst part is that usually after putting a colon, I need to press enter to go to the next line but tabnine just uses that to put this snippet on my code and I need to delete it and go to the next line which double my work

How do I make it so it never shows me this autofill recommendation?